# Python script is exiting with no output and I have no idea why

Tags: python, windows, svn, python-3.x

I'm attempting to debug a Subversion post-commit hook that calls some python scripts. What I've been able to determine so far is that when I run `post-commit.bat` manually (I've created a wrapper for it to make it easier) everything succeeds, but when SVN runs it one particular step doesn't work.

We're using CollabNet SVNServe, which I know [from the documentation](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/csvn/faq/repohooks.html) removes all environment variables. This had caused some problems earlier, but shouldn't be an issue now.

> *Before Subversion calls a hook script, it removes all variables - including $PATH on Unix, and %PATH% on Windows - from the environment. Therefore, your script can only run another program if you spell out that program's absolute name.*

The relevant portion of `post-commit.bat` is:

```
echo -------------------------- >> c:\svn-repos\company\hooks\svn2ftp.out.log

set SITENAME=staging
set SVNPATH=branches/staging/wwwroot/
"C:\Python3\python.exe" C:\svn-repos\company\hooks\svn2ftp.py ^
 --svnUser="svnusername" ^
 --svnPass="svnpassword" ^
 --ftp-user=ftpuser ^
 --ftp-password=ftppassword ^
 --ftp-remote-dir=/ ^
 --access-url=svn://10.0.100.6/company ^
 --status-file="C:\svn-repos\company\hooks\svn2ftp-%SITENAME%.dat" ^
 --project-directory=%SVNPATH% "staging.company.com" %1 %2 >> c:\svn-repos\company\hooks\svn2ftp.out.log

echo -------------------------- >> c:\svn-repos\company\hooks\svn2ftp.out.log
```

When I run `post-commit.bat` manually, for example: `post-commit c:\svn-repos\company 12345`, I see output like the following in `svn2ftp.out.log`:

```
-------------------------- 
args1: c:\svn-repos\company
args0: staging.company.com
abspath: c:\svn-repos\company
project_dir: branches/staging/wwwroot/
local_repos_path: c:\svn-repos\company
getting youngest revision...
done, up-to-date
--------------------------
```

However, when I commit something to the repo and it runs automatically, the output is:

```
-------------------------- 
--------------------------
```

`svn2ftp.py` is a bit long, so I apologize but here goes. I'll have some notes/disclaimers about its contents below it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Usage: svn2ftp.py [OPTION...] FTP-HOST REPOS-PATH

Upload to FTP-HOST changes committed to the Subversion repository at 
REPOS-PATH.  Uses svn diff --summarize to only propagate the changed files

Options:

 -?, --help             Show this help message.

 -u, --ftp-user=USER    The username for the FTP server. Default: 'anonymous'

 -p, --ftp-password=P   The password for the FTP server. Default: '@'

 -P, --ftp-port=X       Port number for the FTP server. Default: 21

 -r, --ftp-remote-dir=DIR   The remote directory that is expected to resemble the
                        repository project directory

 -a, --access-url=URL   This is the URL that should be used when trying to SVN
                        export files so that they can be uploaded to the FTP 
                        server

 -s, --status-file=PATH   Required.  This script needs to store the last 
                          successful revision that was transferred to the 
                          server.  PATH is the location of this file.

 -d, --project-directory=DIR   If the project you are interested in sending to
                               the FTP server is not under the root of the 
                               repository (/), set this parameter.
                               Example: -d 'project1/trunk/'
                               This should NOT start with a '/'.
2008.5.2 CKS
Fixed possible Windows-related bug with tempfile, where the script didn't have
permission to write to the tempfile. Replaced this with a open()-created file
created in the CWD.

2008.5.13 CKS
Added error logging. Added exception for file-not-found errors when deleting files.

2008.5.14 CKS
Change file open to 'rb' mode, to prevent Python's universal newline support from
stripping CR characters, causing later comparisons between FTP and SVN to report changes.
"""

try:
    import sys, os
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
        filename='svn2ftp.debug.log',
        filemode='a'
    )
    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

    import getopt, tempfile, smtplib, traceback, subprocess
    from io import StringIO
    import pysvn
    import ftplib
    import inspect

except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e)
    #capture the location of the error
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    stack_trace = traceback.format_stack(frame)
    logging.debug(stack_trace)
    print(stack_trace)
    #end capture
    sys.exit(1)

#defaults
host = ""
user = "anonymous"
password = "@"
port = 21
repo_path = ""
local_repos_path = ""
status_file = ""
project_directory = ""
remote_base_directory = ""
toAddrs = "developers@company.com"
youngest_revision = ""

def email(toAddrs, message, subject, fromAddr='autonote@company.com'):
    headers = "From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n" % (fromAddr, toAddrs, subject)
    message = headers + message
    logging.info('sending email to %s...' % toAddrs)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.company.com')
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.sendmail(fromAddr, toAddrs, message)
    server.quit()
    logging.info('email sent')

def captureErrorMessage(e):
    sout = StringIO()
    traceback.print_exc(file=sout)
    errorMessage = '\n'+('*'*80)+('\n%s'%e)+('\n%s\n'%sout.getvalue())+('*'*80)
    return errorMessage

def usage_and_exit(errmsg):
    """Print a usage message, plus an ERRMSG (if provided), then exit.
    If ERRMSG is provided, the usage message is printed to stderr and
    the script exits with a non-zero error code.  Otherwise, the usage
    message goes to stdout, and the script exits with a zero
    errorcode."""
    if errmsg is None:
        stream = sys.stdout
    else:
        stream = sys.stderr
    print(__doc__, file=stream)
    if errmsg:
        print("\nError: %s" % (errmsg), file=stream)
        sys.exit(2)
    sys.exit(0)


def read_args():
    global host
    global user
    global password
    global port
    global repo_path
    global local_repos_path
    global status_file
    global project_directory
    global remote_base_directory
    global youngest_revision

    try:
        opts, args = getopt.gnu_getopt(sys.argv[1:], "?u:p:P:r:a:s:d:SU:SP:",
            ["help",
            "ftp-user=",
            "ftp-password=",
            "ftp-port=",
            "ftp-remote-dir=",
            "access-url=",
            "status-file=",
            "project-directory=",
            "svnUser=",
            "svnPass="
            ])
    except getopt.GetoptError as msg:
        usage_and_exit(msg)


    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ("-?", "--help"):
            usage_and_exit()
        elif opt in ("-u", "--ftp-user"):
            user = arg
        elif opt in ("-p", "--ftp-password"):
            password = arg
        elif opt in ("-SU", "--svnUser"):
            svnUser = arg
        elif opt in ("-SP", "--svnPass"):
            svnPass = arg
        elif opt in ("-P", "--ftp-port"):
            try:
               port = int(arg)
            except ValueError as msg:
               usage_and_exit("Invalid value '%s' for --ftp-port." % (arg))
            if port < 1 or port > 65535:
               usage_and_exit("Value for --ftp-port must be a positive integer less than 65536.")
        elif opt in ("-r", "--ftp-remote-dir"):
            remote_base_directory = arg
        elif opt in ("-a", "--access-url"):
            repo_path = arg
        elif opt in ("-s", "--status-file"):
            status_file = os.path.abspath(arg)
        elif opt in ("-d", "--project-directory"):
            project_directory = arg


    if len(args) != 3:
        print(str(args))
        usage_and_exit("host and/or local_repos_path not specified (" + len(args) + ")")

    host = args[0]
    print("args1: " + args[1])
    print("args0: " + args[0])
    print("abspath: " + os.path.abspath(args[1]))
    local_repos_path = os.path.abspath(args[1])
    print('project_dir:',project_directory)

    youngest_revision = int(args[2])


    if status_file == "" : usage_and_exit("No status file specified")



def main():
    global host
    global user
    global password
    global port
    global repo_path
    global local_repos_path
    global status_file
    global project_directory
    global remote_base_directory
    global youngest_revision

    read_args()

    #repository,fs_ptr

    #get youngest revision
    print("local_repos_path: " + local_repos_path)
    print('getting youngest revision...')
    #youngest_revision = fs.youngest_rev(fs_ptr)

    assert youngest_revision, "Unable to lookup youngest revision."
    last_sent_revision = get_last_revision()

    if youngest_revision == last_sent_revision:
        # no need to continue.  we should be up to date.
        print('done, up-to-date')
        return

    if last_sent_revision or youngest_revision < 10:
        # Only compare revisions if the DAT file contains a valid
        # revision number. Otherwise we risk waiting forever while
        # we parse and uploading every revision in the repo in the case
        # where a repository is retroactively configured to sync with ftp.

        pysvn_client = pysvn.Client()
        pysvn_client.callback_get_login = get_login

        rev1 = pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, last_sent_revision)
        rev2 = pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.number, youngest_revision)

        summary = pysvn_client.diff_summarize(repo_path, rev1, repo_path, rev2, True, False)

        print('summary len:',len(summary))
        if len(summary) > 0 :
            print('connecting to %s...' % host)
            ftp = FTPClient(host, user, password)
            print('connected to %s' % host)
            ftp.base_path = remote_base_directory
            print('set remote base directory to %s' % remote_base_directory)

            #iterate through all the differences between revisions
            for change in summary :
                #determine whether the path of the change is relevant to the path that is being sent, and modify the path as appropriate.
                print('change path:',change.path)
                ftp_relative_path = apply_basedir(change.path)
                print('ftp rel path:',ftp_relative_path)

                #only try to sync path if the path is in our project_directory
                if ftp_relative_path != "" :
                    is_file = (change.node_kind == pysvn.node_kind.file)
                    if str(change.summarize_kind) == "delete" :
                        print("deleting: " + ftp_relative_path)
                        try:
                            ftp.delete_path("/" + ftp_relative_path, is_file)
                        except ftplib.error_perm as e:
                            if 'cannot find the' in str(e) or 'not found' in str(e):
                                # Log, but otherwise ignore path-not-found errors
                                # when deleting, since it's not a disaster if the file
                                # we want to delete is already gone.
                                logging.error(captureErrorMessage(e))
                            else:
                                raise
                    elif str(change.summarize_kind) == "added" or str(change.summarize_kind) == "modified" :
                        local_file = ""
                        if is_file :
                            local_file = svn_export_temp(pysvn_client, repo_path, rev2, change.path)
                        print("uploading file: " + ftp_relative_path)
                        ftp.upload_path("/" + ftp_relative_path, is_file, local_file)
                        if is_file :
                            os.remove(local_file)
                    elif str(change.summarize_kind) == "normal" :
                        print("skipping 'normal' element: " + ftp_relative_path)
                    else :
                        raise str("Unknown change summarize kind: " + str(change.summarize_kind) + ", path: " + ftp_relative_path)
            ftp.close()

    #write back the last revision that was synced
    print("writing last revision: " + str(youngest_revision))
    set_last_revision(youngest_revision)     # todo: undo

def get_login(a,b,c,d):
    #arguments don't matter, we're always going to return the same thing
    try:
        return True, "svnUsername", "svnPassword", True
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        #capture the location of the error
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        stack_trace = traceback.format_stack(frame)
        logging.debug(stack_trace)
        #end capture
        sys.exit(1)

#functions for persisting the last successfully synced revision
def get_last_revision():
    if os.path.isfile(status_file) :
        f=open(status_file, 'r')
        line = f.readline()
        f.close()
        try: i = int(line)
        except ValueError:
            i = 0
    else:
        i = 0
    f = open(status_file, 'w')
    f.write(str(i))
    f.close()
    return i

def set_last_revision(rev) :
    f = open(status_file, 'w')
    f.write(str(rev))
    f.close()


#augmented ftp client class that can work off a base directory
class FTPClient(ftplib.FTP) :
    def __init__(self, host, username, password) :
        self.base_path = ""
        self.current_path = ""
        ftplib.FTP.__init__(self, host, username, password)

    def cwd(self, path) :
        debug_path = path
        if self.current_path == "" :
            self.current_path = self.pwd()
            print("pwd: " + self.current_path)

        if not os.path.isabs(path) :
            debug_path = self.base_path + "<" + path
            path = os.path.join(self.current_path, path)
        elif self.base_path != "" :
            debug_path = self.base_path + ">" + path.lstrip("/")
            path = os.path.join(self.base_path, path.lstrip("/"))
        path = os.path.normpath(path)

        #by this point the path should be absolute.
        if path != self.current_path :
            print("change from " + self.current_path + " to " + debug_path)
            ftplib.FTP.cwd(self, path)
            self.current_path = path
        else :
            print("staying put : " + self.current_path)

    def cd_or_create(self, path) :
        assert os.path.isabs(path), "absolute path expected (" + path + ")"
        try: self.cwd(path)
        except ftplib.error_perm as e: 
            for folder in path.split('/'): 
                if folder == "" :
                    self.cwd("/")
                    continue

                try: self.cwd(folder)
                except: 
                    print("mkd: (" + path + "):" + folder)
                    self.mkd(folder)
                    self.cwd(folder)

    def upload_path(self, path, is_file, local_path) :
        if is_file:
            (path, filename) = os.path.split(path)
            self.cd_or_create(path)

            # Use read-binary to avoid universal newline support from stripping CR characters.
            f = open(local_path, 'rb')

            self.storbinary("STOR " + filename, f)

            f.close()
        else:
            self.cd_or_create(path)

    def delete_path(self, path, is_file) :
        (path, filename) = os.path.split(path)
        print("trying to delete: " + path + ", " + filename)
        self.cwd(path)
        try:
            if is_file :
                self.delete(filename)
            else:
                self.delete_path_recursive(filename)
        except ftplib.error_perm as e:
            if 'The system cannot find the' in str(e) or '550 File not found' in str(e):
                # Log, but otherwise ignore path-not-found errors
                # when deleting, since it's not a disaster if the file
                # we want to delete is already gone.
                logging.error(captureErrorMessage(e))
            else:
                raise

    def delete_path_recursive(self, path):
        if path == "/" :
            raise "WARNING: trying to delete '/'!"
        for node in self.nlst(path) :
            if node == path :
                #it's a file.  delete and return
                self.delete(path)
                return
            if node != "." and node != ".." :
                self.delete_path_recursive(os.path.join(path, node))
        try: self.rmd(path)
        except ftplib.error_perm as msg :
            sys.stderr.write("Error deleting directory " + os.path.join(self.current_path, path) + " : " + str(msg))


# apply the project_directory setting
def apply_basedir(path) :
    #remove any leading stuff (in this case, "trunk/") and decide whether file should be propagated
    if not path.startswith(project_directory) :
        return ""
    return path.replace(project_directory, "", 1)

def svn_export_temp(pysvn_client, base_path, rev, path) :
    # Causes access denied error. Couldn't deduce Windows-perm issue.
    # It's possible Python isn't garbage-collecting the open file-handle in time for pysvn to re-open it.
    # Regardless, just generating a simple filename seems to work.
    #(fd, dest_path) = tempfile.mkstemp()
    dest_path = tmpName = '%s.tmp' % __file__

    exportPath = os.path.join(base_path, path).replace('\\','/')
    print('exporting %s to %s' % (exportPath, dest_path))
    pysvn_client.export( exportPath,
            dest_path,
            force=False,
            revision=rev,
            native_eol=None,
            ignore_externals=False,
            recurse=True,
            peg_revision=rev )

    return dest_path    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.info('svnftp.start')
    try:
        main()
        logging.info('svnftp.done')
    except Exception as e:
        # capture the location of the error for debug purposes
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        stack_trace = traceback.format_stack(frame)
        logging.debug(stack_trace[:-1])
        print(stack_trace)
        # end capture
        error_text = '\nFATAL EXCEPTION!!!\n'+captureErrorMessage(e)
        subject = "ALERT: SVN2FTP Error"
        message = """An Error occurred while trying to FTP an SVN commit.

repo_path = %(repo_path)s\n
local_repos_path = %(local_repos_path)s\n
project_directory = %(project_directory)s\n
remote_base_directory = %(remote_base_directory)s\n
error_text = %(error_text)s
        """ % globals()
        email(toAddrs, message, subject)
        logging.error(e)
```

Notes/Disclaimers:

- I have basically no python training so I'm learning as I go and spending lots of time reading docs to figure stuff out.
- The body of `get_login` is in a try block because I was getting strange errors saying there was an unhandled exception in callback_get_login. Never figured out why, but it seems fine now. Let sleeping dogs lie, right?
- The username and password for `get_login` *are* currently hard-coded (but correct) just to eliminate variables and try to change as little as possible at once. (I added the svnuser and svnpass arguments to the existing argument parsing.)

So that's where I am. I can't figure out why on earth it's not printing anything into `svn2ftp.out.log`. If you're wondering, the output for one of these failed attempts in svn2ftp.debug.log is:

```
2012-09-06 15:18:12,496 INFO svnftp.start
2012-09-06 15:18:12,496 INFO svnftp.done
```

And it's no different on a successful run. So there's nothing useful being logged.

I'm lost. I've gone way down the rabbit hole on this one, and don't know where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you have a simple python script that just prints a single line and does nothing else?

Comment: A simple script with nothing but a print statement works. The output shows up in svn2ftp.out.log.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are overwriting your logging level. Try setting both to DEBUG and see what happens.

```
import sys, os
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,  # DEBUG here
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    filename='svn2ftp.debug.log',
    filemode='a'
)
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.ERROR) # ERROR here
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
```

Additionally you are printing in some places and logging in others. I am not sure that the logging library automatically redirects sys.stdout to the logging console. I would convert all print statements to logging statements to be consistent.

Comment: Standarizing on logging sounds like a good idea. Will have to wait for tomorrow.